# Windows Networks available over the internet

Tags: windows, networking

I am trying to develop a windows network audit/discovery application
As I do not have a windows network available at home to test on
I got to wondering whether or not there is any type of "test/sandpit" windows network available over the internet.

does anyone know of such a service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would imagine if there was then it wouldn't be somewhere I would want to go anywhere near with my PC!

The most common way to do what you need would be to create a number of virtual machines to provide you with a network to work with. Tools like VMWare Workstation or Virtualbox will let you do that on your desktop. Alternatively if you don't have the resources then you could look at using one of the many cloud providers such as Amazon or Rackspace to provide you with a cloud based network.

Comment: Dear Sam thanks very much for your time in answering my question